# Reveal the User ID over the url? E.g.: www.domain.com/user/1

Tags: php, sql, laravel, url, dns

What is the best practice?

I have a website, that has a user profile page and you can get to it with domain.com/user/1. Every number reveals the User_ID from my database. I'm curious is this a bad idea? I'm not into SQL injecting, but maybe one can use the information against me. I'm using Laravel and it has some basic protecting against injecting.

What do you think? Should I use random numbers for the user profile or it doesn't matter at all?

Comment: Put it in the session scope and compare the url value to the session value on every page request.

Comment: is that thing that sensitive? its just index anyone can guess it ..auto-incremented still if you want to hide try encrypt() with laravel and append to url

Comment: if you are "really" actually worried about that you could use hash ids to hide the actual value of the id you are exposing, or use their username or something that is unique in the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note : Writing in context to laravel**

> Yea, it depend entirely on the purpose you want to use it for.

Lets say, for example in simple product listing an url that looks like
`http://www.demosite.com/seller/1234/products/1234`

would disclose `vendor id` and `product id` associated. so, even if someone try to do something like

`http://www.demosite.com/seller/1235/products/1232` **would fail if the vendor or product does not exits which is totally fine.**

Also, as you are using laravel likely the selected routes will be only visible to user authenticated so, first level of security is achieved and you only have worry about internal users for which if you are still worried
use **Hashing or encryption** (again it depends entirely on the sensitivity of data.)

You can look here.. for Laravel [Hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing) or [Encryption](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/encryption)

if you have any queries comment back..

Answer (score 2):

If depends!

If there is anything at all sensitive that can be accessed with just the id then it is a problem.

However if there is nothing sensitive – not even when preempting the id of an account before it is created<sup>1</sup> – then there is no issue.

Consider for example https://stackoverflow.com/users/7009480/philipp-mochine which contains your user id here on Stackoverflow.

---

<sup>1</sup> A multi-stage registration would be a problem with this: attacker jumps ahead to the last page and sets authentication details while the real person is still filling in their profile (fix: create the account and password then the user can fill out everything later).